# Using "regardless of"

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Please, tell is this sentence is right.

> They receive requests from all the company employees regardless of
>   locations.

I doubt whether it is right to use the noun after ***regardless*** in a plural form.

Also use it with the preposition ***of*** is proper?

Comment: The preposition ***of*** is perfectly natural in your cited context - but even though they're syntactically "valid", the definite article ***the*** and pluralised ***locations*** aren't particularly idiomatic here. We'd usually say *They receive requests from **all company employees** regardless of **location**.*

Comment: You have to say **Please tell me** or **Please say**.  "Please tell is ..." is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> They receive requests from *any* company employee, regardless of [the employee's] location.

**regardless of** is something many native speakers say.  It means here that the employee's location has no bearing on whether they are willing to accept requests from an employee. Location is not a factor that would cause them to refuse to accept a request.

Comment: And as FumbleFingers said it needs to be in singular form and without an article, right? Like in your edited sentence.

Comment: If we are going to say what is permissible based on how native speakers use this phrase, then there is no absolute rule requiring the singular there or zero-article. You will find phrases like "regardless of prior convictions" and 'regardless of a prior conviction". Personally I prefer to say **without regard for location**.

Comment: FWIW,  I would also say "accept requests".  **receive** does not necessarily have the meaning "accept".